# how to INSERT and DELETE records in 1 query?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, oracle

Hi I want to build a (Follow/Unfollow) button,

which should FOLLOW a page by '**adding**' a record in a table *{table columns are UserID and PageID}* if the record doesn't exist,

or UNFOLLOW a page by '**removing**' the record from the table if the record already exist

I know I can handle this in the PHP code by creating 2 queries, BUT I want to know if I can do it with 1 query using 'if statment' or something else!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IS this on SQL/Server AND/OR on Oracle? You've tagged both.

Comment: And MySQL. Seriously, what is it with all these questions tagging every possible language/platform?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that the Table that you want to add to or remove from is called `User_Page`.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM User_Page WHERE USerID = @userID and PageID = @PageID)
 BEGIN
  DELETE FROM User_Page  WHERE USerID = @userID and PageID = @PageID
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO User_Page (UserID, PageID) VALUES (@userID, @pageID)
 END
```

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you can use the [`MERGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) statement with the [`DELETE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#i2081030) clause, consider:

```
SQL> create table foo(userid number, pageid number, dummy number);

Table created

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE follow(p_userid NUMBER, p_pageid NUMBER) IS
  2  BEGIN
  3     MERGE INTO foo f
  4     USING (SELECT p_userid userid, p_pageid pageid FROM dual) i
  5     ON (f.userid = i.userid AND f.pageid = i.pageid)
  6     WHEN MATCHED THEN
  7        UPDATE SET f.dummy = NULL
  8        DELETE WHERE 1 = 1
  9     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 10        INSERT (userid, pageid) VALUES (i.userid, i.pageid);
 11  END;
 12  /

Procedure created
```

The dummy column is needed because the `MERGE` statement can't update the join column (in the `ON` clause) and the `UPDATE` clause is necessary. Running the statement twice will delete the row:

```
SQL> exec follow(1, 1);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> select * from foo;

    USERID     PAGEID      DUMMY
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1 

SQL> exec follow(1, 2);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> select * from foo;

    USERID     PAGEID      DUMMY
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1 
         1          2 

SQL> exec follow(1, 1);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> select * from foo;

    USERID     PAGEID      DUMMY
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, You can't do it directly. As a workarround, depending of how you lanuch the queries, you can launch two queries in the same sentence using a semicolon as a separator.

Of course, you can always use a stored procedure instead.

However, I don't think that this solutions are good practices. Keep your two queries in the same transaction and call it from the business layer. It will me more mantenible in the future.